# Can we plot NMR pulse sequences according to the conventions of the field?

Tags: plotting

People working with nuclear magnetic resonance (NMR) spectroscopy, or magnetic resonance imaging (MRI), describe their methods using plotted pulse sequences of actions of radiofrequency (RF) excitations, or application of gradient fields, versus time, and typically report their spectra with frequencies increasing from right to left, and images in grey scale. All this is known, and can be found in numerous text books.

I am not aware of an open access package that provides Mathematica users with such plotting capabilities. Both pulse programs, as well as normalised spectra, are always extra work to plot in Mathematica.

I can imagine that it should be easy to specify these diagrams, such that users can control output based on their preferences. For example, a pulse could be described as a set of axes {{RF1, RF2, ...}, {Gx, Gy, Gz}, ..., {Acq1, Acq2, ...}}, followed by specifications of each of these axes {{RF1, Pi/2, t0},{RF1, Pi, t1}, ...,{Gz,{t2,t3}}, {Acq1, t4}} and so on, from which a graphic could be produced.

Furthermore, I could imagine that it would be tremendously useful to have the possibility to plot data from Bruker, Jeol, Magritek, Nanalysis, or Oxford Instruments as standard NMR spectra (1D, 2D, nD, images, etc). This would greatly unify the effort to produce proper and uniform graphics of experimental work.

Is anyone aware of such a facility?

Many thanks, Jan

Comment: Can you actually provide an example with how a plot like that is supposed to look like and some example data to produce it?

Comment: Yes of course. Here is a pulse plot taken from https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11244-019-01209-7. The authors are plotting a so-called pulsed-field-gradient (PFG) sequence. Time runs from left to right. The radiofrequency (RF) channel flips spin ensembles by some denoted angle. Thus 180° is twice as long as 90°, for the same RF strenght. The free induction decay is observable on the RF channel, and produces the echo. The gradient g (points in the z-direction) is repeated at different levels, hence the parallel stripes, one for each repeat.

Comment: The ramps in strength indicate that the gradient cannot be switched instantaneously. See fig 1 in the linked paper.

Comment: For NMR, here is a 1D spectrum from a website at the University of Sydney: https://scilearn.sydney.edu.au/OrganicSpectroscopy/?type=NMR&page=The%20Spectrum The magnetic field strength / frequency is denoted in ppm, which renders NMR spectra comparable. Important, each peak can be integrated, and that data is plotted in the spectrum as a step curve. Essentially, it helps to count the number of protons, for example.